# T-SQL Case functionality

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to structure a `CASE` statement as follows?

For each `Path` column I want to update the `Value` column, but the values aren't being set and I'm not sure how to proceed. The columns are all `nvarchars(255)`.

I've taken this code from an answer on StackOverflow; however in that case the columns listed after `SET` and `CASE` were the same. I realize that there are other methods achieve the same result, but this is the least verbose I've found.

```
UPDATE Database.[dbo].[Table] 
SET Value = 
CASE Path
    WHEN '\Folder1' THEN '0'
    WHEN '\Folder2' THEN 'xyz'
    WHEN '\Folder3' THEN '0'
    ELSE Value 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Value` column doesn't change, then for each row only latest `else` of your case is true. Syntax itself is correct, and it should work as you want. I'd first do `SELECT` to double check that constants in `CASE` correspond to what you have in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE Path
WHEN '\Folder1' THEN '0'
WHEN '\Folder2' THEN 'xyz'
WHEN '\Folder3' THEN '0'
END as val
FROM Database.[dbo].[Table]
```

It should return up to 3 rows ('0','xyz', and NULL). If it returns 1 row only(NULL), then you don't have records where the value of `Path` column equals to any of '\Folder1','\Folder2','\Folder3'.

Note : the syntax of `CASE` you use compares value of `Path` column with constants using `=`. You might have wanted to use another logic, for instance `LIKE`. Then use different form of `CASE` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE 
WHEN Path LIKE '\Folder1%' OR Path LIKE '\Folder3%' THEN '0'
WHEN Path LIKE '\Folder2%' THEN 'xyz'    
END as val
FROM Database.[dbo].[Table]
```

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond with the comprehensive answer a1ex07, really helped me out.